# Procedural material broken in 2.81

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

[image]

How it's meant to look^

I downloaded this wonderful procedural shader setup by Elbriga, which has worked fine in Blender 2.8 – but when I got the new 2.81 version the material preview is broken for some reason. I can't figure out what's wrong.

[image]

How it looks^

Download Link: https://www.cyn-prod.com/projects/wood.php

Comment: Looks fine to me in 2.81 both in *Material Preview* and *Rendered*.

Comment: Huh, [no issues here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hcIu.png). Even with Eevee it looks [some kind of ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EefF6.png)...

Comment: Huh that's odd. Wonder what's janked in my setup. Thanks for the replies! I'll see if I start a new project and see what happens.

Comment: Nope. Even if I start a new file and link/append the material its still messed up. OS is up to date and all.

Comment: @brockmann are you using Windows or macOS? Could it be a Apple thing because I'm using a mac? I even tried 2.82 Alpha version but still the same - multicolored mess.

Comment: Linux @Woody ...

Comment: @brockmann ah of course, my bad to exclude Linux. Well it seems a macOS problem, had no issues on my PC. Thanks for all the help!